# ActiveRecord in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a small project built from scratch and I want to convert it by using CodeIgniter. How can I convert this query string into activerecord? Sorry I am still new to CI.

```
SELECT c.*, p.*, cp.* FROM css c, php p, cplusplus cp WHERE cp.id = p.cp_id AND p.id = c.p_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very is to write CI Active records. You can start learning [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html).

First configure the DB details then load

```
$this->load->database();
```

This is active record way of your query. Not exactly the same but response will same(optimized way)

```
   $this->db->select("*")
              ->from("php")
              ->join("css", "css.pid = php.id")
              ->join("cplusplus", "cplusplus.cp_id = php.cp_id")
              ->get()->result_array(); //Returns multiple records
```

You can use `____->get()->row_array();` for single record.

** Response will be in array format.